# react-native-navigation V2 : How to nest sideMenu inside stackView

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have an initialScreen that checks if the user has logged in before. If yes, user is navigated to the `main` screen and if not, the user is navigated to the `signUp` screen(using `stack navigation`).

This works fine but I am trying to use both `stack` and `sideMenu` navigation. When the user is navigated to the `main screen`, I want open a `sideMenu` when the user clicks on the `sideMenu icon` or `swipe-to-right`.

**This is my `Initalzing` screen**

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native'

import { goToSignUp, goToMain } from './navigation'

import { USER_KEY } from './Config/config'

export default class Initialising extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem(USER_KEY)
      console.log('user: ', user)
      if (user) {
        goToMain()
      } else {
        goToSignUp()
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error: ', err)
      goToSignUp()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Loading</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 28
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
})
```

**This is where I want to nest sideMenu inside `mainScreen`**

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation'

//if user not sign in go to signUpScreen
export const goToSignUp = () => Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    stack: {
      id: 'StackId',
      children: [
        {
          component: {
            name: 'SignUpScreen',
          },
        },
      ],
    }
  }
});

//if user has signed in go to mainScreen
//I want to nest sideMenu in here!!
export const goToMain = () => Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    stack: {
      id: 'App',
      children: [
        {
          component: {
            name: 'MainScreen',
          }
        }
    ],
    }
  }
})
```

My question is, how could I nest sideMenu inside the root navigation? Any comments or advise would be really helpful. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: maybe [createSwitchNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/2.x/switch-navigator.html#docsNav) can help you out

Comment: @flix thanks but I was wondering if I could do it with `react-native-navigation-V2`

Comment: ahh sorry, i'm miss reading the title, i thought you are used react navigation